# NodeJS- Export from SQL Server according to Stream

Tags: sql-server, node.js, streaming

I work on a web application in NodeJS, and now I want add a module for exporting massive records from my SQL Server's database (10.000.000 records) according to stream/socket to a `.CSV` file.
If 100 users downloading data (.csv) from server, increased lot of memory usage  in  ***server*** / ***client***.
***I want if possible, save data(.csv) into hard drive(client), no into server/client Memory(RAM).***

#### Server.js

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = http.Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('Connection is ready!')
    socket.on('get_records', function (data) {
    var connection = new sql.Connection(config, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err.message);
        }

        var request = new sql.Request(connection);
        request.stream = true;

        request.query("Select * from my_table");
        // ... error checks
        request.on('recordset', function (recordset) {
            // Emitted once for each recordset in a query
        });

        request.on('row', function (record) {
            // Emitted for each row in a recordset
            socket.emit('recieve_records', record); //send record by record to client
        });

        request.on('error', function (err) {
            console.log(err.message);
        });

        request.on('done', function (returnValue) {
            // Always emitted as the last one
        });
    });
});
```

**Edit**: See below post
[StreamSaver.js - Error in downloading (Network failed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42262224/streamsaver-js-error-in-downloading-network-failed)

Comment: Are you using Express as a server? Also how do you get records stream? Is it an ordinary Node.js Readable Stream?

Comment: @AntonioNarkevich, I edited my question. please see again.

Comment: Still suggesting you using to use HTTP as socket.io seems to be inappropriate for file downloads. Updated the answer a bit.

Answer (score 1):

If you transfer a file using socket.io there is no easy/robust way to initiate the download dialog. I found 3 solutions to save the file:

1. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30965486/7006062). But you'll have to keep the whole file in RAM before save. + it has max blob size restriction.
2. [FileSaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) module. Same idea, wrapped into a module (5k stars at GitHub). Still restricted to blob size, and keeps everything in memory.
3. [StreamSaver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/streamsaver) module. Doesn't have blob size restriction. But doesn't work at all in Firefox, IE, Edge.

That is why I suggest you to use simple HTTP for file transfers.

Then you could simply use `<a href="path/to/your/endpoint">` tag to download it or use some tricks from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620698/how-to-trigger-a-file-download-when-clicking-an-html-button-or-javascript).

So in case you have Node.js Readable stream that emits objects you can use ['csv' module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv) and convert it to 'csv' on the fly. Then simply pipe it to Express response object.

```js
var csv = require('csv');

router.get('/csv', function (req, res, next) {
 //Handle the connection here, you might decide to use connection pool is supported
 new sql.Connection(config, function (err) {
  if (err) {
   console.log(err.message);
  }

  //You can pipe mssql request as per docs
  var request = new sql.Request(connection);
  request.stream = true;
  request.query("Select * from my_table");

  var stringifier = csv.stringify({header: true});
  //Then simply call attachment and pipe it to the response
  res.attachment('sample.csv');
  request.pipe(stringifier).pipe(res);
 });
});
```

Also checkout the csv-stringify docs as there are useful options such as headers: true (to add headers row) and others.

Comment: 1- Why **socket.io** is not an appropriate mechanism?                                     
2- Please edit _'csv module'_'s link.

Comment: This answer not good for server, bc **increased lot of memory usage in server**.

Comment: @HosseinGanjyar, added reasons why I'd prefer HTTP. Fixes csv link.

Comment: @HosseinGanjyar I've spent a lot of time figuring this out. Let's find the answer. How much did data usage change? Did you try to send data without csv transformation? Still bad (in terms of RAM)?

Comment: @AntonioNarkevich problem is not about transfer data, is about save that over hard drive.