# StreamSaver.js - Error in downloading (Network failed)

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, socket.io

I using StreamSaver and NodeJS together for save 10,000,000 Records into a file with .Json format. After run app and downloaded about many records(200,000 or 300,000 or ....), downloading canceled and abort file.json and show error "***Network failed***" on downloader in browser.
***Why show this error and canceled downloading?***
**Notice**: I haven't any error in console and I downloaded about 500MB or more...So no problem in range/memory.

### Server.js

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = http.Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('Connection is ready!')
    socket.on('get_records', function (data) {
    var connection = new sql.Connection(config, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err.message);
        }

        var request = new sql.Request(connection);
        request.stream = true;

        request.query("Select * from my_table");
        // ... error checks
        request.on('recordset', function (recordset) {
            // Emitted once for each recordset in a query
        });

        request.on('row', function (record) {
            // Emitted for each row in a recordset
            socket.emit('recieve_records', record); //send record by record to client
        });

        request.on('error', function (err) {
            console.log(err.message);
        });

        request.on('done', function (returnValue) {
            // Always emitted as the last one
        });
    });
});
```

### client.js

```
var fileStream = streamSaver.createWriteStream('filename.json');
writer = fileStream.getWriter();
encoder = new TextEncoder();
var counter = 0;

socket.on('recieve_records', function (data) {
    var uint8array = encoder.encode(data + "\n"); // data='every things'
    writer.write(uint8array);
    counter++;
    if (counter > 100000) {
       console.log('100.000 messages downloaded');
       counter = 0;
    }
});
```

[image]

Comment: What is exact error message? Why do you set file extension to `.json` at `.createWriteStream()` if data is `.csv`? Does `.write()` expect a `TypedArray` or string? Have you tried sending data in two responses at 500,000 records each?

Comment: What is exact error message?

Comment: Is error a `RangeError`?

Comment: @guest271314 no....that occured in different time...edited question.

Comment: Greater detail as to what exact error is should be available. You can alternatively use `fetch()`, `ReadableStream`, `Response.body.getReader()`, see [How to solve Uncaught RangeError when download large size json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39959467/how-to-solve-uncaught-rangeerror-when-download-large-size-json), where was able to download an 189 MB file.

Comment: @guest271314 I downloaded about **~500MB**. 189MB is not problem.

Comment: @guest271314 I haven't any error in console.

Comment: Where is error occurring? Is full message of error _"Network failed"_? If 189 MB is not an issue, download 189 MB at a time using pattern where no issue occurred.

Comment: @guest271314 added pic into my question. please see again

Comment: The image does not provide additional description of source of error.

Comment: This is sample...

Comment: I will add a address tomorrow for check this item for u....